# Get sum of MySQL column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in a table that I would like to add up and return the sum. I have a loop, but it's not working.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $sum += $row['Value'];
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: you should either replace this with a SQL query that does the sum, or you should initialise `$sum = 0` before the loop. I'd suggest making a SQL query with a sum() field.

Comment: nothing wrong here except $sum can have some value before loop, whats your query?

Comment: you have to declare the $sum variable above WHILE loop to '0'

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can completely handle it in the MySQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Using PDO (`mysql_query` is deprecated)

```
$stmt = $handler->prepare('SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM codes');
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

Or using mysqli:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM codes'); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

Comment: like this `$sum= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Codes");` with this i get `Resource id #10` but not the sum of all values.

Comment: Try `$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM codes'); $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $sum = $row['value_sum'];`.

Comment: What is the value and value_sum?

Answer (score 14):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableName";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);

$qty= 0;
while ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query_run)) {
    $qty += $num['ColumnName'];
}
echo $qty;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Value) as total FROM Codes");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$sum = $row['total'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Let us use the following image as an example for the data in our MySQL Database:

[image]

Now, as the question mentions, we need to find the sum of a particular column in a table. For example, let us add all the values of column "duration_sec" for the date '09-10-2018' and only status 'off'

For this condition, the following would be the sql query and code:

```
$sql_qry = "SELECT SUM(duration_sec) AS count 
    FROM tbl_npt 
    WHERE date='09-10-2018' AND status='off'";

$duration = $connection->query($sql_qry);
$record = $duration->fetch_array();
$total = $record['count'];

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 5.6 (LAMP) . column_value is the column you want to add up. table_name is the table.

Method #1

```
$qry = "SELECT column_value AS count
        FROM table_name ";

$res = $db->query($qry);

$total = 0;
while ($rec = $db->fetchAssoc($res)) {
    $total += $rec['count'];
}
echo "Total: " . $total . "\n";
```

Method #2

```
$qry = "SELECT SUM(column_value) AS count 
        FROM table_name ";

$res = $db->query($qry);

$total = 0;
$rec = $db->fetchAssoc($res);
$total = $rec['count'];

echo "Total: " . $total . "\n";
```

Method #3 -SQLi

```
$qry = "SELECT SUM(column_value) AS count 
        FROM table_name ";

$res = $conn->query($sql);

$total = 0;
$rec = row = $res->fetch_assoc();
$total = $rec['count'];

echo "Total: " . $total . "\n";
```

Method #4: Depreciated (don't use)

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(column_value) AS count FROM table_name'); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
$sum = $row['count'];
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`$row['Value']` is probably a string.  Try using `intval($row['Value'])`.</strike>

Also, make sure you set `$sum = 0` before the loop.

Or, better yet, add `SUM(Value) AS Val_Sum` to your SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(column) AS total_value FROM table name WHERE column='value'");
$result=mysql_result($result,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get Sum Of particular row value using PHP MYSQL

```
"SELECT SUM(filed_name) from table_name"
```

Comment: You mean using MySQL ?

Comment: we get sum from MYSQL when get result then why we try to make some loop getting  result..

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Codes";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    sum = $row['SUM(price)'];

}

echo sum;
```