# Counting from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to count something from database, to show on my website. Table name "attempts" and table field "bullets". I want count everything from that field. For all users, as it's goes by id's, there are list of users, and I need to count bullets field for all of them. Here's the code for that table. Need to count just bullets for all users.

```
CREATE TABLE `attempts` (
  `username` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `victim` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `bullets` bigint(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

I tried

`$totalbullets = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attempts GROUP BY bullets ");`

but nothing happen'.

Comment: do you want to count "bullet" field for a particular user or for all users

Comment: Define "nothing happen". Also show some data and what you expect.

Comment: put your complete php code here

Comment: For all users. Example: select all ID'S count just bullets. I tried everything u posted, nothing worked or it gives 0.

Comment: And I'm expecting just sum of all bullets from all users , to show on my website with echo.

Comment: then a simple `SELECT SUM(bullets) FROM attempts` should give you the total amount of all bullets ever fired. Does any other query you write return anything from the database? Maybe the connection is not properly set up or sth like that is not working?

Comment: SELECT
    Username,
    Sum(bullets) as Tries
From
    Attempts
Group by
    Username
Order by
    Tries desc ( this give 0 ) and that too, even if there are numbers in that fields.

Comment: `mysql_query` does not return the result of the query. It tells you if it was successful or not. Additionally you need to pass the **connection**. check: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_query.asp

Comment: It's connected to database. <? echo number_format($totalbullets); ?> should return result, but it gives only 0 or nothing, just empty. I tried all solutions you posted, but some show 0 and some just blank. Even if that should be correct, it's not :S

Comment: Please see my updated answer below

Answer (score 1):

Since bullets is an int field you can just have mysql do a math calculation for you because count() will only count the total rows.

From your comments I see you don't know how to use the `mysql_` functions so here it is:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT
                        Username,
                        Sum(bullets) as Total_bullets
                    From
                        Attempts
                    Group by
                        Username
                    Order by
                        Total_bullets desc");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $row['Username'].' : '.$row['Total_bullets'].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT username, SUM(bullets) FROM attempts GROUP BY username
```

Answer (score 0):

### `mysql_query`

does not return the result of the query. It tells you if it was successful or not. *[optionally:  pass the **connection**. Which can be created using `mysql_connect()`]*

check: 
 * http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_query.asp
 * http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Syntax: `mysql_query(query,connection)`

---

I think it should be without the `` ` ``

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attempts GROUP BY bullets "[, connection]);
```

*It will return how many users shot x bullets, if you use the GROUP BY (How many with rows bullet = 1, how many rows with bullet = 2, ...*

Or I would even change it to

```
mysql_query("SELECT attempts.bullets, COUNT('') As numberOfUsers FROM attempts GROUP BY attempts.bullets "[, connection]);
```

Please note `*` or `''` shouldn't make a difference for the result and usually doesn't make a big difference. However `''` makes clear you don't want the database to return any values, only count them.

Answer (score -1):

[Get sum of MySQL column in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808522/get-sum-of-mysql-column-in-php)

`SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;`

In this case there is no need for a group by. Try searching the site next time :)