# How to sum values of a column of a table?

Tags: mysql

```
Book Name           Author Name         No. of Copies   Entry Date
Web Development     Er. Gurbax Singh    7               2015-10-07  
PHP                 Mr. Yash Arora      5               2015-10-06  
DBMS                Mr. Subhash Singla  2               2015-10-30  
Data Structure      Mr. Balwinder Singh 6               2015-11-14  
Multimedia          Dr. Latila Bhutani  3               2015-11-23  
Graphics Designing  Er. Gurpreet Kaur   6               2015-11-23
```

Note: I want sum of no. of copies

Comment: `SELECT SUM(no_of_copies) AS totalBooks FROM tablename`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get sum of mysql column in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808522/get-sum-of-mysql-column-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

use `SUM`

```
SELECT SUM(no_of_copies) AS totalBooks FROM tablename
```

or `Group by sum`

```
SELECT SUM(no_of_copies) AS totalBooks FROM tablename group by BookName
```

Comment: I tried the code below, its giving some errors....... please guide me to improve myself....<?php
$query ="select sum(copies) as totalbooks from booksdetail";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "$result";     
}
?>

Comment: <?php 
$query ="select sum(copies) as totalbooks from booksdetail"; $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 { 
 echo $row['totalbooks']; 
 } 
 ?>

Comment: @Gurpreet - the small table structure that you've posted gives no indication of issued books, so how can you expect us to know the other tables on your database, or how issues are logged in your database.... so how can you expect us to answer this second question

Comment: Name: 
Branch: 
Roll No: 
Library Card No: 
Email: 
Contact No: 
Book Name: 
Author Name: 
Book No: 
Issue Date: 
mm/dd/yyyy
Submit

Comment: I am usint the code below, which is giving errors.... <?php
$query ="select sum as issuedbooks from issue";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['issuedbooks'];     
}
?>

Comment: @Gurpreet - Ask as a new question, then you can actually format this information so that it's readable..... I'm not going to give myself eyestrain and brainache struggling to read a new question that you've posted in a comment, and I doubt that anyone else is..... I'd also recommend reading a few tutorials on SQL, so that you can understand any answers that you get