# why does my array behave like this

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

```
while($pp_info = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpinfo)){

           $product_title = $pp_info['book_name'];
           $books_image = $pp_info['book_upload'];
           $books_price = array($pp_info['book_price']);
 }

 Array ( [0] => 324 ) 
 Array ( [0] => 500 ) 
 Array ( [0] => 543 ) 
 Array ( [0] => 22 )
```

how can I get the sum of each number ?

I use `array_sum($books_price);`

and the outcome is  324 500 543 22

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SUM(book_price) As Total` in your mysql query.

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808522/get-sum-of-mysql-column-in-php) for more detail.

In **PHP**,

```
$book_total = 0;  // define variable outside loop
while($pp_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlpinfo)){
  $product_title = $pp_info['book_name'];
  $books_image = $pp_info['book_upload'];
  $books_price = $pp_info['book_price'];  
  $book_total += $books_price; // perform addition operation
}
echo "Book Total: $book_total";
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @Tubolito: Check this answer. Let me know if you have any query in answer.

Comment: I got a new problem

 if(isset($_POST['updatecart'][$pro_id])){
                $qty = $_POST['qty'][$pro_id];
    

                $special_id = $_POST['updatecart'][$pro_id];
                $sqlqty = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE cart SET qty='$qty' WHERE p_id='$special_id' AND user='$user'");
                      $user = '' . $_SESSION['userName'] . '';

                  $total = $books_price * $qty;

               }

Comment: When I click update .. I wanted to multiply book_price and the quantity .
for example .. book_price = $6 * 6 pcs = $36 .. my problem is I cant total it .. it . Help please

Comment: You need to write this line as below:-   $book_total += $books_price * $qty;

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all your book prices into one array `$books_price` array through  `$books_price[] = $pp_info['book_price'];` and then after loop calculate its sum

```
$books_price = array();

while($pp_info = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpinfo)){

       $product_title = $pp_info['book_name'];
       $books_image = $pp_info['book_upload'];
       $books_price[] = $pp_info['book_price'];
}

$sum = array_sum($books_price);

// For debug
var_dump($books_price)
echo $sum;
```

Comment: are you using `$books_price[] = $pp_info['book_price'];` ? if yes can you write in comment what you get with `var_dump($books_price)` ?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "324" } 324Array ( [0] => 324 ) array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "500" } 500Array ( [0] => 500 ) array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "543" } 543Array ( [0] => 543 ) array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "22" } 22Array ( [0] => 22 )

Comment: @Tubolito the data which you provide can't be one single array `var_dump` seems you are doing something wrong at your side, can you exactly copy past my answer code to your php script instead your current `while( ...` and provide in comment output

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
while($pp_info = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpinfo)){

           $product_title = $pp_info['book_name'];
           $books_image = $pp_info['book_upload'];
           $books_price = array($pp_info['book_price']);
 }
```

to

```
$bookpricearray = array();

while($pp_info = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpinfo)){

             $product_title = $pp_info['book_name'];
             $books_image = $pp_info['book_upload'];
             array_push($bookpricearray,$pp_info['book_price']);
 }

echo $total_price=array_sum($bookpricearray);
```

Comment: @Tubolito : hope u understand