# Insert values to mysql from select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php results page which gets values from submited php form like

```
$sales = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (int)$_POST['sales']);
```

I have an insert query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO daily (date, sales) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$sales')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Now i want to add an extra field to db which will be based on a new select query

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(sales) FROM daily WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'";
```

I've tried to add it to insert sql with no result

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO daily (date, sales, total_sales) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$sales', '$query')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to insert the query into your table rather than the result. Run the query separately and then save just the result.

Comment: In above $query = "Select .....", You have written the query but dose't execute that query. Excute the written query and pass that value

Answer (score 3):

You could use a insert/select

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO daily (date, sales, total_sales) 
        SELECT 
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
             '$sales',
            SUM(sales) 
       FROM daily 
       WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'";
```

in two step you could  execute your,  query get the value and assign to insert  ... eg:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(sales) as tot FROM daily WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'";
mysqli_query($link, $query) ; 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
$myTotal  = $row[0]
$sql = "INSERT INTO daily (date, sales, total_sales) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$sales', '$myTotal')";
```

Comment: This way you won't add the $sales value  to the SUM of sales... Anyway it's the correct way to do so... But i think he's doing this in 2 different steps.

Comment: Yeap i prefer on two different steps

Comment: The only suggestion that worked but i need it in 2 steps

Comment: I don't undertsand because you need two step  .. (one step is better ,, more fast and readable..) but anyway i have update the answer  with a suggestio for two step

Answer (score 0):

You should run that query first, save the results in an array, cycle through the array and add the result in the correct field of your database.

what you are doing now is to add the text of your query in the `total_sales` column of your `daily` table.

You can refer to this answer to inspire yourself: [Get sum of MySQL column in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808522/get-sum-of-mysql-column-in-php)

Also [this](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/insert-statement/inserting-the-result-of-a-query-in-another-table.php) page explains very well what you have to do, scroll down until you reach the example titled "Inserting the result of a query in another table with group by".

Comment: I've tried $query = "SELECT SUM(sales) FROM daily WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'";
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);  but didn't work

Comment: i've edited my answer linking an accepted answer that will help you figuring this out...

Comment: I can't manage it. I tried most of them. $query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(sales) as total FROM daily WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$sum = $row['total'];  Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your mistake is not wanting to understand how this works, but wanting us to tell you how to do this. Read a tutorial on PHP and MySQL, use PDO, since mysql_query has been deprecated since years now. It seems to me that you don't have a clear idea of what you are doing in PHP, leaving out MySQL. To help you a bit, in your last comment, what you are doing is saving the data you need inside the $sum variable. Try to understand better what you are doing first. You need basics...

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked was simple:

```
$result= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT SUM(sales) as valuesum FROM daily);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
$total_sales = $row['valuesum'];
```

I couldn't manage it to work because there was other errors which i found from phpfpm-error.log

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
$sales = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (int)$_POST['sales']);
$query = "SELECT SUM(sales) FROM daily WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'"

$sql = "INSERT INTO `daily` SET `date` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `sales` = ' ".$sales." ', `total_sales` = ($query)";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: I tried $sql = "INSERT INTO daily set date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, sales = '$sales', total_sales = '$query'"; but it doesn't insert values on db

Comment: You missed the brace (). just run as same as the query. "INSERT INTO `daily` SET `date` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `sales` = ' ".$sales." ', `total_sales` = ($query)"