# Simple php - mysql select and insert

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I am not a programmer (duh), I just need to make a really simple tool for populating sql database. First I have html with form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8081/phpSearch.php" method ="post">
Enter code: <input type="text" name="search"><br>
<input type ="submit">
</form>
```

and then php that should connect to MYSQL, search for data according to input (code,name) in one table and then populate another table with the result. And I'm only mising what to put instead of question marks.

```
<?php
$search1 = $_POST['search'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT code,name FROM users WHERE code LIKE '%$search1%'";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO newUsers (newCode,newName) VALUES ('$search1', ??????)";

$conn->close();
?>
```

I'm pretty sure this is easy for you experts, so thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php

Comment: You're missing a lot more. The queries still have to be executed. Am I right in assuming that this code will not be used by strangers, who might try to hack your database?

Comment: We help to fix your code - not to make it. .. What does not work with your exiting code? We need that information to help. ..

Comment: Please provide some more context around what is going wrong with your code above and what you are trying to accomplish. Also as mentioned, those $sql queries will need to be executed

Comment: You never execute the queries. For example `$result = $conn->query($sql);`

Comment: It may be worth looking at INSERT...SELECT queries in MySQL -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784178/insert-values-to-mysql-from-select-query

Answer (score 4):

You could actually do this in a single SQL query:

```
$search1 = "%".$_POST['search']."%";
$sql = "INSERT INTO newUsers (newCode, newName) SELECT code, name FROM users WHERE code LIKE ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $search1);
$stmt->execute();
```

This will insert all the results of the SELECT query directly into the other table, without needing any intermediate processing in PHP. More about the `INSERT...SELECT` query format can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html).

Note I've used prepared statements and parameters - which both executes the query securely and reduces the risk of accidental syntax errors. You can get more examples of this [here](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli).

Also, in a real application you shouldn't log in as root from your web application - instead create a SQL account for the application which has only the privileges it actually *needs*.

Comment: This is it, thank you so much! It's simple and it works. Other ideas were also good, but I couldn't get them to work. Thank you all for your kind help, and just to clarify - I am aware that I need to fix login issue (root), but that's coming later, when I have the necessary functionality. And also, the solution will run on an isolated PC, with local WAMP server, so I don't need particular security at the moment. Thanks again!