# Count sum from column database in PHP

Tags: php, sql

**Update, I think my question is different because this question is not about a specific column but the value of a whole row, I need only need the sum of the column `field_id number 3`.**

I'm having a small problem to get this to work. I have a wp_form on my website where people can fill in with how many people they are coming. I quickly want a overview of the amount of people coming. So I thought I'll grab it from the database with a query. But I'm not getting the results I'm expecting.

My table looks as following:

```
-----------------------------
form_id | field_id | value  |
-----------------------------
20      | 1        | Name   |
20      | 2        | email  |
20      | 3        | 2      |
20      | 4        | yes/no |
-----------------------------
20      | 1        | Name   |
20      | 2        | email  |
20      | 3        | 1      |
20      | 4        | yes/no |
-----------------------------
```

Now I need the `value` of `field_id #3` and have the `sum` of all the values.

I have a connection all working. If I do the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` Where field_id = 3";
```

And `echo $row["value"]` I get all the values from the `field_id #3` 
So i've looked around here and found some query using `SUM`. So I'm trying this, but it doesn't seem to work, I'm probably not using it correctly...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` from field_id = 3";
```

And then `$row['SUM(values)']` doesn't work.

I found this piece of code, but that also doesn't work.

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(field_id) FROM wp_wpforms_entry_fields where field_id = 3" 
// Print out result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Total sum". $row['SUM(column_name)'];
}
```

I'm kind of new to this php and SQL, I'm hoping someone could help me... Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get sum of MySQL column in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808522/get-sum-of-mysql-column-in-php)

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work ? And when do you execute the query ? You should use some prepared statment to secure the query.

Comment: @Jeto Not exactly I need the sum of a specific field `field_id number 3` the link you wrote is not for field.

Comment: Don't you want to SUM(value) not the sum of how many times field_id 3 is in the db * 3.

Comment: you want the sum of what???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this i think:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(field_id) as TotSum3 FROM wp_wpforms_entry_fields where field_id = 3" 
    // Print out result
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "Total sum". $row['TotSum3'];
}
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` is deprecated and should never be used. Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead to get a keyed array.

Comment: @JonJ Updated, i haven't seen the mistake.

Comment: @Jay-oh Remember that for Aggregate Functions, you always need to set a name with AS, to return it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're summing the field_id, not the actual value.

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(value) FROM wp_wpforms_entry_fields where field_id = 3";
```

for clarity, here is the full code with echo (taken from chosen answer, so credit to him).

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(value) as TotSum3 FROM wp_wpforms_entry_fields where 
field_id = 3"; 
// Print out result
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "Total sum". $row['TotSum3'];
}
```

Comment: What do I echo? Because this breaks the page using my current code.

Comment: @Jay-oh Do it like in the answer you've chosen as correct, with the full given code where the SUM is for field_id not for the value is incorrect if i understood your post correctly. if you SUM field_id you will get rowcount*3 not the actual values of those rows.

Answer (score 0):

In sql when working with tabels 'column names' sometimes ,one need take care of this -> `` ,types of commas.This will also work as per your requirement

```
$results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT SUM(`field_id`) FROM wp_wpforms_entry_fields where `field_id` = 3");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){


 echo "Total sum: ". $row["SUM(`field_id`)"];

}
```