# Get the sum of all the hours

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am doing a project with PHP and MySQL. I have this problem.

This is my code

```
<?php 

$proyecto = $_POST['id'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "dbuser";
$password = "dbpass";
$dbname = "proyectos";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT `horas`, `trabajador` FROM `horas` WHERE `proyecto` LIKE '$proyecto' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();

?>
```

It takes a parameter from a post request and do a search in the database database looks like this:
[image: database looks like this]

So I want to get as result the sum of all the hours (horas column) that are made by the same worker (trabajador column). Example of result:

> Prueba1: 8 hours in total, Prueba2: 9 hours in total

I am stuck trying to dinf they way to sum when 1 or more fields must be the same, I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Start by explain where you're stuck. You're making a query to the database, then what happens? You're also _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: You should also use `=` instead of `LIKE` when matching an exact string in MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I know the sql injection part but I am only going to use it (localhost) so it isn't so important. I am stuck in this part: 

"So I want to get as result the sum of all the hours (horas column) that are made by the same worker (trabajador column)."

Comment: Because your question is missing an actual explanation of your issue. You've just posted some code and a requirements spec. without even commenting on it. Is it fetching the data from the database result? Is it the calculation? If yes, then what does any of those columns contain? Show us the database schema and some example data, expected result and what you're currently getting.

Comment: Adding data/code samples as image isn't a good solution.

Comment: That still doesn't change the fact that we programmers would prefer to see [SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html) instead of graphic arts.

Comment: lol it's not a big table so it's more visual to see it with an image I think.

Comment: Not for me, like in Matrix movie, you can see a blondies and brunets here, I can see tables and columns :p. And more seriously. after this screenshot, we don't know i.e. what data types are specified for the columns (although it doesn't matter in this case of course). Therefore it's better to show create statement as text. Back to your problem. `sum()` function is probably thing you should check. Anyway as other commented you **MUST** use prepared statements for security reasons.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, It's my first time showing mysql problems in the platform so I don't know how to do it well. Thanks

Comment: Votes are how we rate content. This question doesn't add anything new to our collection of questions so it will not be rated high. Don't take downvotes personally, we simply rate the content to have a proper collection of questions & answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get sum of MySQL column in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808522/get-sum-of-mysql-column-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use **sum** function to add the number of hours for each worker along with **GROUP BY** clause to group workers.Formatted Query is like:

```
SELECT SUM(horas) AS Hours,`trabajador` 
FROM `horas` 
WHERE `proyecto` 
LIKE '%".$proyecto."%' 
GROUP BY `trabajador`
```

In your code,

```
$select = "
    SELECT SUM(horas) AS Hours, `trabajador` 
    FROM `horas` 
    WHERE `proyecto` LIKE ? 
    GROUP BY `trabajador`
";

$sth = $conn->prepare($select);
$sth->execute(['%'.$proyecto.'%']);

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

Note: You better switch to MYSQL prepared statements to keep your data secure and for better database connectivity practices.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OP uses [tag:php] tag and shows PHP context in a sample of his code. He definitely opens the query for injection. So I can agree with _suggestion_ about preparing statements.

Comment: I am going to be the only person that will use that so it won't be necesary

Comment: @maiksidana I am using the code you have provided but when I try to "echo" the result, I don't get anything as result. WHat's happening?

Comment: @AlvaroArtano you need to fetch the records using PHP mysqli functions and use them accordingly. I have updated the code to give you an idea. use it wisely.

Comment: @Dharman I have tried to give an idea to OP about prepared statements

Comment: Why is this wrong? `echo "<tr> <td>$row["trabajador"]</td><td>$row["Hours"]</td> </tr>";`

Comment: @AlvaroArtano I need to see your code to know more

Comment: @AlvaroArtano _Why is this wrong_ What is wrong???

Comment: @maniksidana please do not mix `mysqli` and `PDO` usage.

Comment: I don't know why I'm not able to write code. Here's an image [link](https://imgur.com/K6w2c3Y)

Comment: Syntax error. Try replacing line with this: echo "<tr><td>".$row['trabajador']."</td><td>".$row['Hours']."</td></tr>";

Comment: @biesior okay.sure. you have written a well-explained answer. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** answer by **maniksidana** explains how to use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` and is in general valid. However, it mixes `mysqli` and `PDO` approches. Here you have sample how to use it with `mysqli` (as your question uses it) and why it's important to use prepared statements at all. Just add some dummy data to your table end execute it. Personally I'd suggest to go with PDO only instead, but it's matter of taste.

```sql
INSERT INTO `horas` (`fecha`, `horas`, `proyecto`, `trabajador`) VALUES
 ('2020-08-08', 3, 'foo bar baz', 'Joker1'),
 ('2020-08-09', 4, 'ello pomello', 'Joker2');
```

```php
<?php 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$proyecto = "ProyectpDePrueba'; DELETE FROM horas WHERE 1; -- bye bye data";
$proyecto = "ProyectpDePrueba";
$proyecto = "ProyectpDePrueba' OR 1=1 -- no more execution";


// Wrong
$sql = "
    SELECT SUM(horas) AS Hours, `trabajador` 
    FROM `horas` 
    WHERE `proyecto` LIKE '$proyecto'
    GROUP BY `trabajador`
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo '<pre>Wrong' . PHP_EOL;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}

// Correct
$sql = "
    SELECT SUM(horas) AS Hours, `trabajador` 
    FROM `horas` 
    WHERE `proyecto` LIKE ? 
    GROUP BY `trabajador`
";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $proyecto);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
echo PHP_EOL . 'Corrcet' . PHP_EOL;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_r($row);
}


$conn->close();
```

Comment: Why do you show both the wrong an correct way? Would it not be simpler to just show the correct way?

Comment: It's for demonstrating why it's important. I'm still surprised why people don't understand that. At least OP (or any) can copy this and see what's the differece.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think this question adds anything new to the SO. I think I will vote to delete this in 2 days.

Comment: Its quite possible, especially, that has lot of duplicates, just let's hope that at least OP will learn some **basics**. If it was experienced, contributor I would end with rude comment and downvote.

Comment: I don't think any contributor deserves a rude comment. Downvote based on the content is appropriate.